# String print function x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to create a function in x86 assembly that can take any given string (of any length) and print it out to DOS video memory to be printed out on screen. I have managed to do something like this but only for a specified length (e.g. a whole extended register). Any help?

Comment: Do you have any code I can go off of?

Comment: Did you use any interrupts ? If i can remember correctly mov ah, 09h  int 21h ; prints a saved string

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pick a delimiter and then print up to that delimiter (instead of just using a count).  Should be pretty straightforward for you if you can already do it by count.

Comment: It's straightforward either way. But we don't know what problem the OP is facing.

Comment: Indeed.  More explanation would help, I have no idea what could be causing an issue for someone that can already do it the other way.